# SSRS : Failure writing file <servername> The network name cannot be found

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I'm newbie on MS SQL and SSRS. I try to send report via mail and Windows File Share. But i'm getting this error.

> Failure writing file \ogdtek\reports\Report2 : The network name
>   cannot be found

The log file is here. Where is the error? When reporting or saving to path(\ogdtek\reports\Report2). I can see report on

```
http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReportProject2%2fReport2

       at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.FileShareDeliveryProvider.FileShareProvider.SaveReport(Notification notification, SubscriptionData d)
subscription!WindowsService_8!770!12/04/2013-01:27:16:: i INFO: Error writing file Report2 to path \\ogdtek\reports
notification!WindowsService_8!770!12/04/2013-01:27:16:: e ERROR: Error occurred processing subscription 068c6fdd-b076-4504-b3bc-9ce8459fce84: Failure writing file \\ogdtek\reports\Report2 : The network name cannot be found.
```

Thanks. Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Try with  (\ \ogdtek\reports\Report2) Without parenthesis.

I think you have missed the leading (\ )

Comment: thanks you for answer. I add but, same log same error message

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was receiving this same error and it was driving me nuts.  I ended up needing to enable the folder for sharing with the NETWORK SERVICE user.  Not sure if this is proper/secure but worked for me...

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro and I went to the folder and right clicked.  I then went to properties then the Sharing tab.  Clicked Share... and added "NETWORK SERVICE"  I also changed the permission level to Read/Write.

I also had given both the user that was accessing the folder and the network service full permission level, but you will probably only need to add the read write execute permissions.  To do this right click on the folder again and go to the Security tab.  Click Edit... then Add... Type your User in the textblock and click Check Names.  Then OK.  Then set the permission for that user.    Do the same for NETWORK SERVICE.

One other thing I noticed is that I get an error if I try to save a report with a name of a file already in that folder.  (Just a heads up...)